# Traefik HA with persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, traefik, persistent-volumes, traefik-ingress

Is there currently any way to utilize kubernetes persistent volumes instead of a KV store in order to store Let's encrypt certificates?

From the documentation, storing let's encrypt information inside a json file cannot be used to share info across traefik pods. But I was wondering about other solutions, maybe boltdb on a shared volume?

Comment: why would you store certificates in the persistent volume?

Comment: Why not add them as secrets?

Comment: Traefik is able to detect the certificates needed and generate/renew them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [official document of Traefik HA](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#as-a-key-value-store-entry), it seems you have only one option in order traefik detect those certificates within a cluster mode.

> **As a Key Value Store Entry**
>
> ACME certificates can be stored in a KV Store entry. This kind of storage is **mandatory** in cluster mode.